# Error CS0012 The type 'IUnityContainer' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced

Tags: c#, unity-container, prism-6

The IUnityContainer property "Container" exist in intellisense but the implementation reference is not found. The fix is pointing to an earlier version of Unity, (4.0.0.0). I'm using version 5.3.2. Is there an additional reference I can Add to fix the error?

The figure is the error:
Error CS0012 The type 'IUnityContainer' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. install Microsoft.Practices.Unity 4.0.0.0. And the second figure are the NuGet packages I currently installed.

Thank you for your support and answer.

King

[image: Reference to old version of Unity]
[image: NuGet packages referenced]

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47542873/use-prism-unity-unitybootstrapper-with-unity-iunitycontainer

Comment: Tanks you. They recommended using Prism 7.0. That solved the issue.